# maximum possible value of $d$

Tags: number-theory

We  are  given  three  integers $a , b,$  and $c$  such  that $a ,  b,  c, 
 a + b − c, a + c − b, b + c − a ,$ and $a + b + c$ are seven distinct primes. Let 
 $d$ be the difference between the largest and smallest of these seven primes. 
 Suppose that $800$ is an element in the set {$a + b, b + c, c + a $}. Determine 
 the maximum possible value of $d$ . What I did:  $a,b,c\geq 3$ (odd primes, if $a$ is  even,then $a+b-c$ is even too and hence are not distinct ) $\implies a+b+c$ is the largest prime and WLOG, let $a$ be the smallest one.Then $b+c\geq a+b$ and $a+c$ implying $b+c\geq 800$.Since, $b+c-a\geq 0 \implies a\leq (b+c\geq 800)$.Here I am stuck, how to bound $a$(i don't know if that's necessary) and get the upper bound for $d$. Am i on the right track??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that without loss of generality we can choose $a+b=800$, and again, as you suggest, we can try to maximize $b+c-a$ while minimizing $a$.

For the well definition of the problem we need $a\geq |b-c|$ and $c\leq a+b=800$. The two biggest primes smaller than 800 are (you can check on [this list](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt)) $787$ and $797$, and their difference is $10$. So we need $a$ to be at least $10$ and such that its sum with $787$ or $797$ is $800$. This clearly suggests the following choice:

$$a=13, \qquad b=787, \qquad c=797.$$

Which leads to:

$$a+b-c=3, \qquad a+c-b=23, \qquad b+c-a=1571.$$

Again using the list above you can check that we have been lucky and those are all distinct primes. Then we have actually computed (not only bounded) the maximum vale $d$, which is:

$d = b+c-a -a = 1571-13= 1558.$

The maximality follows by construction.